# Should we make [strongly-typed] a synonym of [strong-typing]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

It seems that people use the [strongly-typed](/questions/tagged/strongly-typed) tag in combination with other tags like [dataset](/questions/tagged/dataset), [view](/questions/tagged/view), [helper](/questions/tagged/helper) or [enum](/questions/tagged/enum), when what they really mean is:

2. [strongly-typed-dataset](/questions/tagged/strongly-typed-dataset)
3. [strongly-typed-view](/questions/tagged/strongly-typed-view)
4. [strongly-typed-helper](/questions/tagged/strongly-typed-helper)
5. [strongly-typed-enum](/questions/tagged/strongly-typed-enum)

We're considering synonymizing [strongly-typed](/questions/tagged/strongly-typed) to [strong-typing](/questions/tagged/strong-typing), which would effectively force users to use the more specific version of the "strongly-typed" tags, but I thought I'd find out what the community thinks first.

Comment: As someone who knows about strong typing, I approve. First, there are questions about other concepts (related to ASP.NET? A subject I know nothing about) that need to be retagged, e.g. [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strongly-typed+asp.net-mvc) should probably have one of the `strongly-typed-xxx` tags.