# How to rename Tag elastic-search to elasticsearch?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I would like to propose renaming [elastic-search](/questions/tagged/elastic-search) to [elasticsearch](/questions/tagged/elasticsearch).

Reasons:

1. Everyone in the community have agreed. (see hopefully in the comments in some hours)
2. It is stated on the website as [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)
3. It is stated on wikipedia as [ElasticSearch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElasticSearch)
4. I can't create a new 'elasticsearch' tag (an error will appear). This would be sufficient for me and I could manually move the existing questions to it.

Comment: [DOWN WITH THE HYPHEN!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/55384/162704)

Comment: Great and long overdue idea!

Comment: A thousand times yes!

Comment: Definitely a good idea.

Comment: Does anyone know how to finally do this? Attract some users with high enough karma or how?

Comment: As the creator of elasticsearch, it would do a great service to the elasticsearch community.

Comment: The hyphenated version is both ugly and incorrect, voting for the change!

Comment: Totally agree with this one!

Comment: Fairly obvious-and-trivial.

Answer (score 7):

Completed: [elastic-search](/questions/tagged/elastic-search) --> [elasticsearch](/questions/tagged/elasticsearch).