# Merge all questions tagged by [google] and [earth] into [google-earth]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I've discovered meaningless tag [earth](/questions/tagged/earth) (26). [Many of the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/earth+-google+-google-earth) tagged by it are also tagged by [google](/questions/tagged/google).

Obviously they should be tagged by [google-earth](/questions/tagged/google-earth) instead. Please merge them into.

And what do you think about a synonym? Or ban.

Comment: 26 should be easy enough to retag. Then you could perhaps kill off the earth tag, although that will happen automatically I think.

Comment: A synonym is a bad idea for a meaningless tag :P.  Better just to retag and let the vague `[earth]` die.

Comment: @Bart: Honestly I don't want to retag all of them manually. Also a moderator could fully ban the [earth] tag.

Comment: @MatthewRead: Right. Added an option to ban it.

Comment: Well, then I'll go ahead and retag them. That should solve it I'd say.

Comment: It's 24 now... but hardly any are tagged both.

Comment: I've retagged a fair bunch of them by now (correcting other issues as I saw them) There are 4 left where I'm not entirely sure how to retag them, or if they should be around at all. Perhaps others can pitch in?

Comment: I could have done this in the time it took to write this question...

Comment: Cleared up those last four.  Also closed the crap ones.

Comment: @casperOne Thanks for that. Wasn't entirely sure on those.